# auto.arima "no suitable ARIMA model found" for measuring dependency between debt and GDP

Tags: r, time-series, arima

In my studies I've been working recently on dependency between debt and GDP growth in USA from 1966 to 2015. I used logged and differenciated GDP time series data and combined it with 0/1 debt-to-GDP time series data which takes value 0 when the debt-to-GDP level is below some arbitrary value and 1 when it's above. I have made 41 such arrays, depending on arbitrary level, and tried to estimate ARIMA model through `auto.arima` method in "forecast" library and then I'd like to select the best model selecting the best information criterion (let's say Akaike).

However, using `auto.arima` on series returned with `No suitable ARIMA model found`. Could somebody tell what is the reason for it and how can I estimate it?

Here is the data I use:

gdp time series:

```
Time Series:
Start = 1966 
End = 2015 
Frequency = 1 

               gdp
 [1,] 8.150000e+11
 [2,] 8.617000e+11
 [3,] 9.425000e+11
 [4,] 1.019900e+12
 [5,] 1.075884e+12
 [6,] 1.167770e+12
 [7,] 1.282449e+12
 [8,] 1.428549e+12
 [9,] 1.548825e+12
[10,] 1.688923e+12
[11,] 1.877587e+12
[12,] 2.085951e+12
[13,] 2.356571e+12
[14,] 2.632143e+12
[15,] 2.862505e+12
[16,] 3.210956e+12
[17,] 3.344991e+12
[18,] 3.638137e+12
[19,] 4.040693e+12
[20,] 4.346734e+12
[21,] 4.590155e+12
[22,] 4.870217e+12
[23,] 5.252629e+12
[24,] 5.657693e+12
[25,] 5.979589e+12
[26,] 6.174043e+12
[27,] 6.539299e+12
[28,] 6.878718e+12
[29,] 7.308755e+12
[30,] 7.664060e+12
[31,] 8.100201e+12
[32,] 8.608515e+12
[33,] 9.089168e+12
[34,] 9.660624e+12
[35,] 1.028478e+13
[36,] 1.062182e+13
[37,] 1.097751e+13
[38,] 1.151067e+13
[39,] 1.227493e+13
[40,] 1.309373e+13
[41,] 1.385589e+13
[42,] 1.447764e+13
[43,] 1.471858e+13
[44,] 1.441874e+13
[45,] 1.496437e+13
[46,] 1.551793e+13
[47,] 1.615526e+13
[48,] 1.669152e+13
[49,] 1.739310e+13
[50,] 1.803665e+13
```

debt (50% threshold):

```
     debt%gdp
 [1,]        0
 [2,]        0
 [3,]        0
 [4,]        0
 [5,]        0
 [6,]        0
 [7,]        0
 [8,]        0
 [9,]        0
[10,]        0
[11,]        0
[12,]        0
[13,]        0
[14,]        0
[15,]        0
[16,]        0
[17,]        0
[18,]        0
[19,]        0
[20,]        0
[21,]        0
[22,]        0
[23,]        0
[24,]        1
[25,]        1
[26,]        1
[27,]        1
[28,]        1
[29,]        1
[30,]        1
[31,]        1
[32,]        1
[33,]        1
[34,]        1
[35,]        1
[36,]        1
[37,]        1
[38,]        1
[39,]        1
[40,]        1
[41,]        1
[42,]        1
[43,]        1
[44,]        1
[45,]        1
[46,]        1
[47,]        1
[48,]        1
[49,]        1
[50,]        1
```

Then I intersect them and put into `auto.arima` model.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "intersect", but you should pass your debt-to-GDP ratio variable as the `xreg` argument. Aside from that, you may be getting errors because of numerical overflow. I would try using GDP in billions of USD, not in USD.

Comment: This isn't really clear (& won't be on topic on [SO], because it isn't really a programming question). But I think you are trying to find an ARIMA model for a set of 0s followed by a set of 1s. That isn't the kind of data a standard ARIMA is supposed to work with, so it isn't surprising it complains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered a similar problem when I was trying to run auto.arima with one of my explanatory variables. I took the square root of the variable and auto.arima worked just fine. The problem might be that the values in your GDP variable might be too large and might be creating a numerical overflow.

Comment: This is the correct answer. (+1) If the response variable is `sqrt`ed, `log10`ed or even simply divided by `1000`, `auto.arima` works "fine".